WearOS 5 Watch Face Format RadialGradients?
I'm trying to just fill the background of a WearOS 5 Watch Face Format with a RadialGradient:
<PartDraw x="0" y="0" width="450" height="450" pivotX="0.5" pivotY="0.5" alpha="255">
    <Variant mode="AMBIENT" target="alpha" value="0"/>
    <Ellipse x="0" y="0" width="450" height="450">
        <Fill color="#80000040" >
            <RadialGradient centerX="225" centerY="225" radius="225"
                    colors="#ff000040 #ff000010" positions=""/>
        </Fill>
    </Ellipse>
</PartDraw>

However all I seem to get on the WearOS 5 emulator is a solid fill, whereas I am expecting to see a gradient that ramps down from the centre.
Can anyone suggest why this doesn't work?

Have you tested the gradient with different colors? The ones you are using are too similar, test with different colors just to check

Yes I have tried #ffffffffff and #ff000000 and still no signs of any RadialGradient. My feeling is that the only thing that works is the Fill colour.

Just to add, but if you remove the fill colour, then it fails XML verification and fills in solid white. So fill works, but the RadialGradient seems to be ignored.

I've created a Google Issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/361823996

Same issue here. Would be nice if Google could give us even a shred of support for stuff like this.

You need to define positions for your colors
colors="#ff000040 #ff000010" 
positions="0 1"

With three colors it will be something like
colors="#000000 #ffff00 #ffffff" 
positions="0 0.5 1"

This should resolve your issue :)

Thanks. That has worked. A shame they don't default / fail XML verification if they aren't present ;)

Yep, I guess that's not something easy to implement as it would require checking attribute values. Anyway, for finding bugs, you can also check logcat and watch for renderer errors - com.google.wear.watchface.runtime (Google), com.samsung.wear.watchface.runtime (Samsung)
